# VBA how move a user form without titlebar and borders

Tags: vba

I am using this code [VBA Code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17452849-598c-410b-8675-b1e585d0e7e7/userform-without-titlebar-and-borders?forum=exceldev) to UserForm without titlebar and borders.
Works perfectly ok but I would like to allow the user to  move around the displayed userform in the screen. Ad the moment I display the form on the bottom of the screen

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()     
    Call RemoveTitleBar(Me)     
End Sub
```

Code in Module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Sub RemoveTitleBar(frm As Object)
    Dim lStyle          As Long
    Dim hMenu           As Long
    Dim mhWndForm       As Long

    If Val(Application.Version) < 9 Then
        mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", frm.Caption) 'for Office 97 version
    Else
        mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", frm.Caption) 'for office 2000 or above
    End If
    lStyle = GetWindowLong(mhWndForm, -16)
    lStyle = lStyle And Not &HC00000
    SetWindowLong mhWndForm, -16, lStyle
    DrawMenuBar mhWndForm
End Sub

Sub ShowForm()
    UserForm.Show False
End Sub
```

Comment: The standard way to move a form/dialog around the screen is using the titlebar.

Comment: The code in the differently titled duplicate does exactly what you want.